# Mysql shows Different duration

Tags: mysql

I am trying to speed up select query but encountered a problem. That is when i run query it shows 1.4sec on duration but in profiler it is shows 0.00025sec.
Is there any difference in these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had THE same thing a while ago. Are you running the query through à webserver like apache? One of the apache servers couldn't resolve localhost correctly. If you modify host to 127.0.0.1. IT Will work

Comment: I can't access the mysql server machine. Anyway all i want was reason. I get it from this answer